# Find $\int_a^b x \sin x dx $ , given $ \int_a^b |\sin x| dx$ and $\int_0^{a+b} |\cos x| dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

If $ \int_a^b |\sin x| dx =8 $ and $ \int_0^{a+b} |\cos x| dx =9$ , then what is the value of $\int_a^b x \sin x dx $ ?

I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Please help.

Comment: Do we know $a$ and $b$? Did you try integration by parts?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$a+b=4.5\pi\\b-a=4\pi$$

Comment: You are genius man!

Comment: And how did you arrive at that ?

Comment: @Angle so are you!

Comment: @misao note that $$\int_{\pi}|\cos x|dx=\int_{\pi}|\sin x|dx=2$$